# EJB - How to transfer complex object to presentation tier?

Tags: java, service, ejb, javabeans, facade

i'm new to Ejb developing so this might be a newbie question.
I'm developing an application with the common service facade pattern; in this way, my local and remote interface can't know my session bean parameters, so i can only pass simple data between facade and presentation layer.
Which is the best solution to made possible to pass the same content of my bean between facade and presentation layer? Should i duplicate in some way my bean to made it visibile outside to presentation layer?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SessionBean should not be transferred between service layer and presentation layer. Typically your presentation layer should have a reference of your remote or local service interface(s) which is initialized using the `@EJB` CDI framework.

Behind the scene:

The CDI framework then inject an instance of your service interface implementation. If you are using the service remotely, it uses RMI technology to get that instance and transfer the stub using JRMP protocol.

I think you don't want to transfer these SessionBeans between those layers. You need to pass complex DTOs (data transfer objects) as argument to the SessionBean's methods. Is my understanding right?

If so you may want to create some `POJO` (plain old java objects which contains some properties or fields and some setter getter methods + at least a default no-arg `constructor`) which implements `java.io.Serializable` interface.

In this case you can use this java objects as the arguments of the SessionBean's method.

Hope this would be helpful,

Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @staefi
My only problem is that i've different projects for:
A) presentation
B) interfaces
C) bean and facade - 
A) have dipendence on B), C) have dipendence on B)
So, where can i put my DTOs?

Comment: @dbocca: some of your DTOs maybe just some POJOs which are equivalent to your Entity classes(EntityBeans). In this case it is better to put them in the Data Access layer of your project(maybe the c) project).    In other cases they may reside in your B)interfaces project, because they are used in the arguments of methods in those interfaces. I don't think you need them in the data access layer.

Comment: i thinks i'll put DTOs in B) project. Many thanks! :)